# Efficiently condensing several ifelse statements

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following lines of code (where I recode specific values in my age variable) that I would like to condense using base R, ideally into one or two lines. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ibr.sub$age
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ifelse(ibr.sub$age == 4, 3, ibr.sub$Age.recode)
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ifelse(ibr.sub$age == 20, 18, ibr.sub$Age.recode)
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ifelse(ibr.sub$age == 22, 24, ibr.sub$Age.recode)
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ifelse(ibr.sub$age == 26, 24, ibr.sub$Age.recode)
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ifelse(ibr.sub$age == 31, 30, ibr.sub$Age.recode)
```

Comment: `case_when`, or perhaps a join using a lookup table (like a data.table join by referece)

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page. In particular a complete reproducible example should be provided inlcluding all inputs. so that others can work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution replacing with a named vector, your entry data could have more values not recoded if neccesary:

data:

```
ibr.sub <- tibble(age = c(4,4,5,6,20,22,23,22,26,31,30,31))
```

Solution:

```
recode_vec = c("4" = "3", "20" = "18", "22" = "24", "26" = "24", "31" = "30")
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- as.numeric(recode_vec[as.character(ibr.sub$age)])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 2
     age Age.recode
   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     4          3
 2     4          3
 3     5         NA
 4     6         NA
 5    20         18
 6    22         24
 7    23         NA
 8    22         24
 9    26         24
10    31         30
11    30         NA
12    31         30
```

In case you want to keep data in Age.recode with values from age not in recode vector, you need to check if each value produce `NA` and then take the value from age:

```
ibr.sub <- tibble(age = c(4,4,5,6,20,22,23,22,26,31,30,31, 3, 3))
recode_vec = c("4" = "3", "20" = "18", "22" = "24", "26" = "24", "31" = "30")
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(recode_vec[as.character(ibr.sub$age)]), ibr.sub$age, recode_vec[as.character(ibr.sub$age)]))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 14 × 2
     age Age.recode
   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     4          3
 2     4          3
 3     5          5
 4     6          6
 5    20         18
 6    22         24
 7    23         23
 8    22         24
 9    26         24
10    31         30
11    30         30
12    31         30
13     3          3
14     3          3
```

**Code explanation**:
You define `recode_vec` that it´s just a named vector (each element in vector have a name associated, left side of `equal` is name and right side, the value):

```
> recode_vec
   4   20   22   26   31 
 "3" "18" "24" "24" "30"
```

In this way, you have like a dictionary. `ibr.sub$age` is numeric, so you cast to character to work with `recode_vec` (`as.character(ibr.sub$age)`).

Now, to access elements in a named vector, you just have to past the name of element between brackets. Ex:

```
> recode_vec["4"]
  4 
"3" 
> recode_vec["5"] # "5" don´t exist in vector, so return NA
<NA> 
  NA
```

If you pass a vector with names, (in this case names are the values in `ibr.sub$age` like chars) then get that vector translated:

```
> recode_vec[c("4", "4", "5")]
   4    4 <NA> 
 "3"  "3"   NA
```

Finally you have check with `ifelse` clause values translated like `NA` (use directly `is.na` that return logical value) to replace this cases with original data in column `age`. All this produce a character vector, so optionally you can convert to numeric with `as.numeric`.

Comment: Thanks! ibr.sub$age already has previous values in my dataframe, so I would be appending the converted values (4->3) to those already existing values. So for instance, say ibr.sub$age has 10 cases of "3" already and 2 cases of "4". I would want to convert those two cases of "4" to "3" to get a total of 12 cases of "3" in Age.recode. How would I modify your code to accomplish this?

Comment: I edit my answer in this case @ericm, for example I add two "3" values to test data that don´t have to be recoded.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to walk me through the logic of your code? @juanbarq

Comment: Of course! Maybe explanation is too long, I text it in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**1) arithmetic** Multiply each condition by the value it should produce and then in the second line return the input value if none matched or the original input otherwise.  If the only input values are among the conditions tested then the last line could be omitted (although it won't hurt).  If any value is to be recoded to zero, say 100 is to be recoded to 0, then change the last line to `(y == 0 & x != 100) * x + y` ; however, that situation does not occur in the example.

```
x <- 25:31 # test input
y <- 3 * (x == 4) + 18 * (x == 20) + 24 * (x %in% c(22, 26)) + 30 * (x == 31)
(y == 0) * x + y
## [1] 25 24 27 28 29 30 30
```

**2) car::recode**  The car package has a recode function that allows compact specification:

```
x <- 25:31 # test input
car::recode(x, "4=3;20=18;c(22,26)=24;31=30")
## [1] 25 24 27 28 29 30 30
```

**3) dplyr::case_match** This is new in dplyr 1.1.0:

```
x <- 25:31 # test input
dplyr::case_match(x, 4 ~ 3, 20 ~ 18, c(22, 26) ~ 24, 31 ~ 30, .default = x)
## [1] 25 24 27 28 29 30 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
current <- c(4, 20, 22, 26, 31)
new <- c(3, 18, 24, 24, 30)

i <- match(ibr.sub$age, current)
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ibr.sub$age
ibr.sub$Age.recode[i] <- new[i]
```

In only three instructions:

```
i <- match(ibr.sub$age, c(4, 20, 22, 26, 31))
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ibr.sub$age
ibr.sub$Age.recode[i] <- c(3, 18, 24, 24, 30)[i]
```

---

If column `age` has values not in the vector `c(4, 20, 22, 26, 31)`, the `match` instruction will have `NA`'s in it and the indexing will give an error. Try instead

```
i <- match(ibr.sub$age, c(4, 20, 22, 26, 31))
ok <- !is.na(i)
ibr.sub$Age.recode <- ibr.sub$age
ibr.sub$Age.recode[ i[ok] ] <- c(3, 18, 24, 24, 30)[ i[ok] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is using `tidyverse`.

```
ibr.sub %>%                 # your data.frame
 rename(age= Age) %>%       # rename col from Age to age
 mutate( age = case_when(   # case_when : what to change in each case
    age == 4 ~ 3,           # when age == 4, change to 3
    age == 20 ~ 18,         # same thing
    age == 22 ~ 24,
    age == 26 ~ 24,
    age == 31 ~ 30,
    TRUE ~ age) )           # if the value is already TRUE, keep it.
```

It will return this data frame (without the col `Age`, that I have added just for illustration purpose):

```
  id Age age
1  1   3   3
2  2   4   3
3  3   5   5
4  4  20  18
5  5  21  21
6  6  22  24
7  7  26  24
8  8  31  30
```